# Deranged hippo person

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues, geography

> 1. Statue suing deranged hippo person (11)
> 2. Baltic port is original pope's German castle (12)
> 3. Animator and universe are perplexing snowy riddle (11)
> 4. Pop star and French city confusedly lock javelins (12)
> 5. Stamp a bayonet hiding body of water (8)
> 6. Glad Reeves disoriented in swamp region (10)
> 7. Island opposing lock and east (7)
> 8. Stationery, short Saudi and soft drink mess up no palaces (9)
> 9. Dutch Caribbean city is body part and sandy shore (9)
> 10. Pronoun from Leon and pal from Lyon in Bohemia mining district (5)

Where are we?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Statue suing deranged hippo person (11)

> **ST AUGUSTINE** (anagram of "statue suing")

Baltic port is original pope's German castle (12)

> **ST PETERSBURG** (St. Peter's + burg (Ger.))

Animator and universe are perplexing snowy riddle (11)

> **DISNEY WORLD** (anagram of "snowy riddle")

Pop star and French city confusedly lock javelins (12)

> **JACKSONVILLE** (two word plays: (Michael) Jackson + ville (Fr.), anagram of "lock javelins")

Stamp a bayonet hiding body of water (8)

> **TAMPA BAY** (sTAMP A BAYonet)

Glad Reeves disoriented in swamp region (10)

> **EVERGLADES** (anagram of "glad reeves")

Island opposing lock and east (7)

> **KEY WEST** (opposites of "lock" and "east") respectively

Stationery, short Saudi and soft drink mess up no palaces (9)

> **PENSACOLA** (two wordplays: pen + SA + cola, anagram of "no palaces")

Dutch Caribbean city is body part and sandy shore (9)

> **PALM BEACH** (palm + beach)

Pronoun from Leon and pal from Lyon in Bohemia mining district (5)

> **MIAMI** (mi (Sp.) + ami (FR.))

We're in

> **FLORIDA**

Comment: All correct. Nice work!